# Upload file on server through PHP [CodenameOne]

Tags: php, image, file-upload, ftp, codenameone

I want to upload `image` file on server, because not found any way to upload file directly on server from CodenameOne. I convert image in Base64 format and send to php file then in php again decode image and tried to upload. But same also not working. Can you please tell me how do i solve this problem ?

My PHP Code :

```
<?php

define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'public_html/appFiles/GKQuiz/userProfilePicture/');
//$Imagecode=$_POST['Image'];


//Base64 String already added in $Imagecode
$Imagecode="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";

$img=base64_decode($Imagecode);
//echo $img;
$uid=uniqid();

$ftp_server = "example.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "example.com", "123");

if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, UPLOAD_DIR . $uid . ".jpg", $img, FTP_BINARY))
{
  echo "Successfully uploaded";
}
else{
  echo "Error uploading";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the found answer for same as below.

Corrected PHP Code :

```
<?php

define('UPLOAD_DIR',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/appFiles/GKQuiz/userProfilePicture/');

// after $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. your root inside public_html folder if any or '/'.

$Imagecode=$_POST['Image']; // parameter

$img=base64_decode($Imagecode);
$uid=uniqid();

$file = UPLOAD_DIR . $uid . '.jpg';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $img);

if ($success)
{
  echo $uid.'.jpg';
}
else
{
  echo "error";
}

?>
```

In CodenameOne your code may be as below :

```
if (profilepic!=null) {
ImageIO imgIO = ImageIO.getImageIO();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imgIO.save(profilepic, out, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG, 1);
byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();
String Imagecode = Base64.encode(ba);
//System.out.println("data :"+Imagecode);
request = new ConnectionRequest(){
     @Override
     protected void handleErrorResponseCode(int code, String message) {
           System.out.println("Code :"+code+" Msg :"+message);
     }

};
request.setPost(true);
request.setHttpMethod("POST");
request.addArgument("Image", Imagecode);
request.setUrl("http://example.com/filename.php");
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(request);
}else{
     System.out.println("Unable to upload");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [PHP: move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077470/how-do-i-post-a-picture-image-using-the-io-codenameone#10330801) is a full example, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) has a builtin standard upload API thru support for the multipart request HTTP standard in [MultipartRequest](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html).

[MultipartRequest](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html) seamlessly handles the binary base64 etc.

```
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.addData("myFileName", fullPathToFile, "text/plain")
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
```

Java servlet code to intercept this should look like that:

```
@WebServlet(name = "UploadServlet", urlPatterns = {"/upload"})
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 100, // 10 MB
        maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 150, // 50 MB
        maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 200)      // 100 MB
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Collection<Part> parts = req.getParts();
        Part data = parts.iterator().next();
        try(InputStream is = data.getInputStream()) {}
            // store or do something with the input stream
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not a PHP guy but a quick google search landed me on [w3c school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) with this

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```